# windows: command line used to launch a program

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

How can I find out the command line options a program was launched with under windows?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail please. Is this a program you've written, or any program that's been launched by the user?

Comment: awesome question. never needed this before, but it's an amazing idea in and of itself. do tell more, why you need it :)

Comment: I assume that this belongs on superuser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial132.html

in short:
use the Process Explorer utility created by Sysinternals (now owned by Microsoft; which is probably why vista and windows 7 now have a similar functionality already present in task manager)

Comment: BTW: SysInternals is now a part of Microsoft: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx

Answer (score 3):

On vista... You can

- go to the task manager
- Click View --> Select Columns
- Add the command line column.

To do this programatically, run "tasklist -v" to a file and then split up the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the command line of another process programmatically you should probably read [Why is there no supported way to get the command line of another process?](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/23/9440784.aspx):

> Commenter Francisco Moraes wonders
>   [whether there is a supported way of
>   getting the command line of another
>   process](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/pages/407234.aspx#540069). Although there are
>   certainly [unsupported ways of doing
>   it or ways that work with the
>   assistance of a debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/mithuns/archive/2006/02/18/534893.aspx), there's
>   nothing that is supported for
>   programmatic access to another
>   process's command line, at least
>   nothing provided by the kernel. (The
>   WMI folks have come up with
>   [Win32_Process.CommandLine](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372.aspx). I have
>   no idea how they get that. You'll have
>   to ask them yourself.)

If you are trying to retrieve the command line of your own process you can use [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156.aspx).

Answer (score -3):

Try running the .exe but with the /? flag.

Comment: no. these are the POSSIBLE options. the question was AFTER the app started, what options WERE used.